# C# WinForms cannot set focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

Im currently facing the problem that when i try to set focus on some control (textBox), nothing happens, maybe i just overlooked something.(somewhere i found that focus is "low-level" method and that select() should be used instead, however, it doesnt work as well)

From form Login, i launch new instance of EncryptPSW form

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EncryptPSW ePSW = new EncryptPSW();
        ePSW.setOsLog(false, this);
        ePSW.ShowDialog();        
    }
```

On Button(which is located on EncryptPSW form ) click event i call fill method

```
public void fill()
    {
        if (textBoxPSW.Text.Length == 8)//psw has to be 8 chars long
        {
            if (save)//determinating whether save or fetch of data should be done
            { login.launchSave(textBoxPSW.Text,this); }
            else { login.launchOpen(textBoxPSW.Text,this); }
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("The password must contain 8 characters");}
    }
```

Which launches either save or open method from Login (my problem is just with open, since during save i dont need to do anything with Focus)

```
public void launchOpen(string psw,EncryptPSW ePSW)
    {

        ePSW.Close();
        Encryptor.DecryptFile("loggin.bin", psw, this); //decrypting data and setting textBoxes Text property into the fetched ones
        setFocus();

    }
```

After all the work is done, setFocus() should be called in order to set focus and other properties.

```
public void setFocus()
    {
        textBoxDatabase.Focus();
        textBoxDatabase.SelectionStart = textBoxDatabase.TextLength - 1;
        textBoxDatabase.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

I tried so many different ways, like:

Calling setFocus() from within EncryptPSW_FormClosed
Calling whole open process after the EncryptPSW is closed (from within EncryptPSW_FormClosed)
and many more, however i dont remember it all.

In the case of Form_Closed the weird thing is, that when i tried to show a message box from there instead of setting focus (just to see where the problem might be), it's showed before the EncryptPSW form is closed.

My only guess about this is that the instance of EncryptPSW is somehow blocking Login form and it's controls

I hoped i described my problem well enough and that it makes at least a bit of sense ;]

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Releis

Comment: That is not a probelm. Where your textBoxDatabase resides??

Comment: is the textbox visible when you call Focus()?

Comment: that textBox is located on Login form and yes, it's visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the textbox is in the login form, and you are opening the EcryptPWS from it as a dialog (child), your login form will not be able to set focus to anything. You will need to set focus after it is closed. You can do this:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(EncryptPSW ePSW = new EncryptPSW())
    {
       ePSW.setOsLog(false, this);
       if (ePSW.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           textBoxDatabase.Focus(); 
       }
    }
} 

public void launchOpen(string psw,EncryptPSW ePSW) 
{ 
    ePSW.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    ePSW.Close(); 
    Encryptor.DecryptFile("loggin.bin", psw, this); //decrypting data and setting textBoxes Text property into the fetched ones 
}
```

Comment: When the user closes the EncryptPSW form (he misclicked, changed mind or w/e) i dont wanna change focus

Comment: @Releis Little bit confused there on what you mean by "changed mind or w/e"

Comment: User clicks that he wants to open stored account informations, psw request form pops up, however, he might decide not to or he remembers that he misclicked, that he actually didnt want to do that or any other reason to close that form. Is it clear now?;]

Comment: sorry, was out for a while. Works as well, tvym :]

Answer (score 0):

OK this maybe the ugliest thing I saw round this but.

using

```
public void setFocus() 
    { 
        textBoxDatabase.Focus(); 
        textBoxDatabase.SelectionStart = textBoxDatabase.TextLength - 1; 
        textBoxDatabase.SelectionLength = 0; 
    }
```

Change your code at

```
public void launchOpen(string psw,EncryptPSW ePSW)  
    {  

        ePSW.Close();  
        Encryptor.DecryptFile("loggin.bin", psw, this); //decrypting data and setting textBoxes Text property into the fetched ones  
        setFocus();  

    }
```

to

```
delegate void settingfocus();
public void launchOpen(string psw,EncryptPSW ePSW)  
    {  

        ePSW.Close();  
        Encryptor.DecryptFile("loggin.bin", psw, this); //decrypting data and setting textBoxes Text property into the fetched ones  
    settingfocus sf = new settingfocus(setFocus);
    this.BeginInvoke(sf);

    }
```

This worked for me

(Sorry for apparently thinking insert "this" before procedure, and change line x to this was legable)

Comment: Maybe I'm too dumb, but could ya please use sentences? I dont get ya at all :x

Comment: There.. if that doesnt make sense now, I give up

Comment: Working, thx. If you wouldnt mind, 2 questions ;]
1. Whats so ugly there?
2. Do ya know what the problem was?

Comment: the form didnt have focus yet to do the job, so it needed to queue it.  Its ugly because Im sure theres a better way

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The last one (hope it doesnt bother ya) Could ya point out or suggest some better way? Or is it like "I'd have to see all the code"? I love when ppl tell me better way of doing something.. (thats not irony, i mean, i like to improve myself)

Comment: This is the way I've found.. I havent found or seen others, its similar in the way to the old win32 postmessage, so it queues it up and does it. If I knew a better one, Id give you it